# Self pointer, using with C++ from Objective C

Tags: objective-c, syntax, properties, objective-c++, self

I am having a slight confusion with the self pointer. I understand that if I want to use self in objective C, I need to pass it as a parameter e.g.

```
someFunction(id self)
{

}
```

What I'm slightly confused about however is that if I want to use self's member variables, I get the following error

Property 'browser' not found on object of type '__strong id'.

I've defined browser in my header file as:

```
@property webBrowser* browser;
```

I am then trying to call a function of my webBrowser class in my c++ function:

```
[self.browser StartSearch:self];
```

The error occurs in the line above. The function is definitely called correctly if I instead pass self's member variable as a parameter instead. This feels rather hacky though.

Any explanation as to why it doesn't work and what an alternative would be, would be great.

Comment: By convention on Objective-C methods start with a lowercase letter and classes with an uppercase letter. Following these conventions makes code more readable.

Comment: I'm coming from a C++ background so I apologise.

Comment: No apology necessary, just trying to be helpful, I too came from C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use property syntax with dot, you need to provide the compiler with the exact type, for example by casting the `id` pointer to the type of your class. If you do not want to use the exact type or cast, use method call syntax:

```
[[self browser] StartSearch:self];
```

Comment: This one was perfectly suitable for my needs but I'm sure the other answer is just as valid.

Comment: In general using the correct type in place of `id` is a better practice as it is both specific and allows the compiler to perform static type checking.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify the parameter type rather than using a generic `id`:

```
void someFunction(MONObject * self) {
    [self.browser StartSearch:self];
}
```

Or if you feel you really, really, really need the type erasure (e.g. for compilation firewall), you might consider rewriting it this way:

```
// Some.mm
void someFunction(id self) {
    MONObject * object(self);
    [object.browser StartSearch:self];
}
```